# How to kill processes launched by "&" in bash?

Tags: bash

I wanted to run script `./startMegaTrolling.sh 100000000000000000000000` in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ];then 
    let "LAST = $1 - 1"
    for i in `seq 0 $LAST`
    do
        php trolling.php --processNumber=$1 &     #here
    done
fi
```

But how to get pid of all launched processes by this method?
I tried put the `>> pids.txt` `#here`, but it does not work. I want to have got second script to kill all launched processes.

Comment: You might want to read more about [Bash job control](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control). Oh, and you're not creating *threads* but *processes*.

Comment: Did you try this `ps -ef|grep startMegaTrolling.sh`

Comment: Sorry, missspelling, I mean processes, not threads

Answer (score 2):

Use `$!` to access the pid of the most recently launched background process. Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^- shebang is mandatory since we use bash-only features
if (( $# )); then
  for (( i=$1; i>0; i-- )); do
    php trolling.php --threadNumber="$1" &
    echo "$!" >>pids.txt
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the process ids as you start the processes, then kill them all later.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ];then 
    LAST=$(( $1 - 1 ))   # let is a bit antiquated
    for i in `seq 0 $LAST`
    do
        php trolling.php --threadNumber=$1 &
        pids="$pids $!"
    done
fi

# Later on
kill $pids
```

Technically, an array is a better than a space-separated string for collecting
a series of items, but since a process ID is guaranteed to be a simple integer,
it works fine here.

---

For full POSIX compliance (which isn't required by the question, based on the `bash` tag), you can't use either `seq` or a C-style `for` loop, and will have to use a `while` loop instead.

```
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
    LAST=$(( $1 - 1 ))
    i=0
    while [ "$i" -ne "$LAST" ]; do
        php trolling.php --threadNumber="$1" &
        pids="$pids $!"
        i=$((i+1))
    done
fi
```

Comment: If there isn't an external requirement to keep the list on disk (which, rereading, there isn't), this is certainly more efficient / better practice. I'm keeping my own answer around only because of this one's dependency on the non-standard `seq`.

Comment: Agreed. I guess the fact that you can always write a `while` loop kept POSIX from adopting a standard implementation for `seq` (or some other functionally similar command)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

pid: `ps aux | grep <NAME_OF_YOUR_APP> | awk '{print $2}'`

then:

```
kill -9 $pid  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9`; that's a last resort for buggy programs.

Comment: ...also, no reason to grep the process table for your own direct children; you find out their PID when you launch them.

Comment: if you want to kill processes immediately after creating them in the same script chepner has the best answer. My answer here was if you want to use a different stop script called for example from a /etc/init.d/ script

Comment: My preferred way to do this with a separate shutdown script is with a lockfile and `fuser -k` to kill only the processes that have the lockfile open. That way you have a stronger assurance of only hitting your real targets than what grepping `ps` gives you -- you don't want to also kill `vim <NAME_OF_YOUR_APP>`, after all.